# What is תיקון שבת

Tags: shabbat

I have Bencher which includes a section called תיקון שבת. It just seems to be all of משניות שבת.

What is the idea behind תיקון שבת?

Answer (score 4):

[Tikkunei Shabbat](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=58355&st=&pgnum=1) was published anonymously in Cracow in the early seventeenth century, purportedly containing passages that Arizal recommended be recited during *shabbat*, based on Kabbalistic considerations.

The recitations include the entirety of *mishnayot masechet shabbat*, split between the three *shabbat* meals.